# Magento 1.9 get cart total based on site ID or site code

Tags: magento-1.9

I have magento installation that contains 3 site. Now i want to get the cart total for each site and show in one place. 
Is there any way to get the cart total based on site ID or site code ?

Comment: cart total based on website id or store id ?

Comment: based on site id or site code.

Answer (score 2):

**Try This :-**

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId;
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()->addFieldtoFilter('store_id', array('eq' => $storeId));

foreach ($quote as $quotes)
{
    $cartTotal = $quotes->getGrandTotal();
}
```

Comment: Thnkx buddy :)..

Answer (score 1):

Try below way..

```
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId;
    $quote_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_collection')->setStoreId($storeId);
     foreach ($quote_collection as $quote) {
        $cartTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
     }
```